# Pandas- create rows that show the sum of all items by date minus the specific item (creating ex-item rows for each item)

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

So I have panel data that shows metrics for each item over a course of time

```
date    item    value
1/1/2017    a   1
1/1/2017    b   2
1/1/2017    c   4
1/2/2017    a   6
1/2/2017    b   4
1/2/2017    c   3
1/3/2017    a   6
1/3/2017    b   4
1/3/2017    c   3
1/4/2017    a   2
1/4/2017    b   3
1/4/2017    c   4
```

And what I want to do is create rows for each item for each date that takes the sum of all values for that date, subtracts it by the item, then divides by total number of items. Would look something like:

```
date    item    value
1/1/2017    a   1
1/1/2017    b   2
1/1/2017    c   4
1/1/2017    ex-a    2.5
1/1/2017    ex-b    1.5
1/1/2017    ex-c    0.25
1/2/2017    a   6
1/2/2017    b   4
1/2/2017    c   3
1/2/2017    ex-a    0.5
1/2/2017    ex-b    2.5
1/2/2017    ex-c    4.75
```

how would I go about doing this? I'm assuming I'd have to group by date and create a variable that gets the sum of all values for each date, and then loop through each item. Appreciate the help

Comment: the excel function I'm using is just (SUM(A1:C1)-A1)/3

Comment: yeah exactly- in the example above I divided by 2 by accident, sorry about that

Comment: Do you always have 3 items per date? If so, it may be better table design to make each date a row. The columns would be date, a, b, c, ex-a, ex-b, and ex-c. This would also make it easier to perform this calculation.

Comment: nah I have 14 items- this is just an example for simplicity's sake. thanks for the help!

Comment: but is is consistently 14 items or does it vary?

Comment: consistently it's 14 items- can you try an example? dont really follow

Comment: do you have the ability to change the shape of your data or does it have to be in one column?

Comment: I mean I guess I could, I just don't think it would be inefficient and wouldn't be dynamic in case I ever have to add/remove items. what are your thoughts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158902/discussion-between-dick-thompson-and-eric-ed-lohmar).

Answer (score 0):

I'll talk through a process:
- Use groupby to aggregate to the date and item, resetting the index to the date. This is dataframe A
- Use groupby to aggregate to the date, taking the sum and count. This is dataframe B
- Join data frames - B will join multiple rows to A. Subtract each value in A from the aggregate sum in B, and then divide the result by count of rows given in B.

Does that make sense? It's several steps.

Comment: how do I do this? and create new variable names? am confused as to why I have to create several tables

Comment: You need a data frame for each level of aggregation. Think of it as different columns in Excel, with the difference that in Excel you can have columns share an index just by sharing a row, where in Pandas there's not a row to make that association.

It'd look something like:
df_A = df.groupby('date','item')['value'].sum().reset_index()
df_B = df.groupby('date')['value'].agg(['sum','count']).reset_index()
df_join = df_A.join(df_B on date, join = 'inner')

Then df_join contains the sum by date and item from A, the sum by date from B, the count by date from B.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the ability to change the shape of your data to something like:

```
           a   b   c
    date
1/1/2017   1   2   4
1/2/2017   6   4   3
```

then we can iterate through each row, calculate the values, then add them.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1/1/2017', '1/2/2017'],
                   'a': [1, 6],
                   'b': [2, 4],
                   'c': [4, 3]})
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

cols = df.columns.values
num_cols = len(cols)

for col in cols:
    df[f'ex-{col}'] = 0

i = 0
for date, row in df.iterrows():
    row_sum = row.values.sum()
    for col in cols:
        df[f'ex-{col}'].iloc[i] = (row_sum - row[col]) / num_cols

    i += 1

print(df)
```

outputs:

```
          a  b  c      ex-a      ex-b      ex-c
date
1/1/2017  1  2  4  2.000000  1.666667  1.000000
1/2/2017  6  4  3  2.333333  3.000000  3.333333
```

Comment: so it still doesn't work... getting an error on the line `df[f'ex-{col}'] = 0` that it's invalid syntax. What does this line do?

Comment: Sorry, the strings that start with `f'` are new to 3.6 and I use them a lot. you can replace that with `df['ex-' + col]`. It sets all values in the new columns to 0, so they can be replaced with real values later.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the code is flexible in that the DataFrame can contain any number of columns and it will work without changing it, but it does still assume that all of the dates have the same number of items.

Comment: can't convert in object to str implicitly. so in the example my items are strings- is this affecting the function?

Comment: While they do need to be of some numerical type in the DataFrame, the issue gets is with the string formatting again. Change it to `df['ex-' + str(col)] = 0`